# Sorting by two criteria for a final result

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, java-8

The setup is as follows: I have a set of Classroom objects `{MATH | SCIENCE | ENGLISH}`. I also have a Map with `Period` as key and a set of `studentIds` as value. This is returned from a `getPeriodStudentMappingForClassroom()` method. Now, as input, I am given the string `"MATH, ENGLISH, SCIENCE"` which indicates the order in which to return `studentIds` (the number of options are fixed). I also have another string that has any number of periods ordered such as `"B, A"` (there can be any number of periods). Here is a sample visualization:

```
Classroom MATH:
Period A -> Set<Integer> studentIds
Period B -> Set<Integer> studentIds

Classroom ENGLISH:
Period A -> Set<Integer> studentIds
Period B -> Set<Integer> studentIds
```

As output, I would like the `studentIds` returned sorted by classroom and periods in such a way that first I get all `studentIds` for `Period B`. These `studentIds` for `Period B` are sorted in the classroom order `"MATH, ENGLISH, SCIENCE"`. Then I get the `studentIds` for `Period A` sorted in the classroom order `"MATH, ENGLISH, SCIENCE"`. So for ex:

```
Input:
String classroomOrder = "MATH, ENGLISH, SCIENCE"
String periodOrder = "B, A"
public Map<String, <Set<Integer>> getPeriodStudentMappingForClassroom(String classroom)

Output:
Set<Integer> studentIds
Ex.
Period A studentIds in Math classroom
Period A studentIds in English classroom
Period A studentIds in Science classroom
Period B studentIds in Math classroom ...
```

I can of course create any helper methods and structs to contain info but I cannot change the `getPeriodStudentMappingForClassroom()` method and must use it. Can anyone please guide me on how to construct this toy problem solution?

Comment: What have you done so far to solve the problem? Right now this question reads like a list of requirements rather than a focused, specific question.

Comment: It's a toy problem modeled after a more complex one for a personal project.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you have posted your code (small compilable example) and described what you are getting and what you what to get instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its an interesting problem. Not sure why it hasn't been answered yet. Assuming you have a class `ClassRoom` which encapsulates period, course names and student ids as follows

```
public static class ClassRoom {
    private String period; // A or B
    private String courseName; // MATH, SCIENCE or ENGLISH
    private Set<Integer> studentIds;

    public ClassRoom(String period, String courseName, Integer... studentIds) {
        this.period = period;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.studentIds = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(studentIds));
    }

    public String getPeriod() {
        return period;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public Set<Integer> getStudentIds() {
        return studentIds;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Period='" + period + '\'' +
                ", CourseName='" + courseName + '\'' +
                ", studentIds=" + studentIds;
    }
}
```

then the sorted list of classes can be printed as follows

```
    List<String> order = Arrays.asList("MATH", "ENGLISH", "SCIENCE");

    classes.stream().sorted(
            comparing(ClassRoom::getPeriod)
                    .thenComparingInt(c -> order.indexOf(c.getCourseName())))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output

```
Period='A', CourseName='MATH', studentIds=[3, 4, 89, 90, 78]
Period='A', CourseName='MATH', studentIds=[34, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Period='A', CourseName='MATH', studentIds=[2, 3, 4, 5, 232]
Period='A', CourseName='SCIENCE', studentIds=[1, 2, 3, 4, 57]
Period='A', CourseName='SCIENCE', studentIds=[34, 2, 3, 5]
Period='B', CourseName='ENGLISH', studentIds=[2, 5, 7]
Period='B', CourseName='ENGLISH', studentIds=[1, 2, 34, 3, 12]
```